# Can I "rollback" a VirtualBox to the last saved state?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to set up a Windows version with some software, then mess with the kernel with driver development, then rollback to the (good) state I saved Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Snapshot and then roll back to the Snapshot you saved. That should do what you want. You can also make a copy of the VM and restore the copy when done testing.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-snapshots-in-virtualbox/

**Creating a snapshot**

> You can create a snapshot when a VM is either on,
> saved, or off. I'll demonstrate the process of taking a snapshot when
> the VM is powered on; I'll show how to do this with a Red Hat
> Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7.3 VM.
>
> Once the machine is up and running click Machine | Take Snapshot. A
> new window will appear, prompting you for a name and a description of
> the snapshot (Figure A). It's important to fill out the name and
> description because you might take multiple snapshots, and you don't
> want to get those snapshots confused; plus, this allows you to restore
> back to multiple points in the configuration.

**Restoring a snapshot**

> Say you're working in your VM, and you make a
> change that breaks the system...what do you do? You roll back to one
> of your previous snapshots. To do this, it's as simple as creating a
> snapshot, with a couple of caveats.
>
> First and foremost, the VM you want to work with must not be running.
> You can restore a snapshot if the VM is either in a saved state or
> powered off. To restore a state, do the following.
>
> Select the VM to work with from the left pane in the main window.
> Click the Snapshots button in the upper right corner. Right-click the
> snapshot you want to restore. Click Restore Snapshot (Figure C). In
> the resulting window, uncheck the box for Create A Snapshot Of The
> Current Machine State. Click Restore. Allow the restore to complete.